# How to choose a random value from a list in robot framework?

Tags: python, robotframework

I have a list of variables,

```
@{Example} = One Two Three
```

I want the list of variables, randomly choose an item from the list.

Comment: what's your input, and expected output?

Comment: your title asks how to make a for loop, but the body of the question is asking how to pick a random item from a list. Those are two different questions.

Comment: Entry = @{Example} = One Two Three
Exit =   @{Example}[One]

Comment: I need it to be random

Comment: What have you tried as a possible solution?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The simplest solution is to call python's [random.choice](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.choice) method with the built-in [Evaluate](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Evaluate) keyword. You can use robot's [extended variable syntax](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#extended-variable-syntax) to pass the list of choices into the function.

Here's a short example that will print a random value to stdout each time you run it:

```
*** Variables ***
@{Example}  One  Two  Three

*** Test Cases ***
Example
    ${value}=  Evaluate  random.choice($example)  random
    log to console  \nvalue: ${value}
```

Comment: Change ($example) to (${example}).

Comment: @BahubaliPatil: no, robot supports `$example` as a special case in the `Evaluate` keyword.